# NodeJS App for Rocket Chat iframe auth throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have a nodejs app that throws the error every time I try and start the app using the command "node index.js":

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

I understand how generic this error is, but I need a bit of direction. This application specifically is for iframe-auth detailed in rocket.chats documentation for utilizing a 3rd party API to login instead rocket chat's native login system.

The entire code of the app is here:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request-promise');
var session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
const rocketChatServer = '*redacted*';
const rocketChatAdminUserId = '*redacted*';
const rocketChatAdminAuthToken = '*redacted*';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//CORS in case you need
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*redacted*'); 
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    next();
});

// define middleware
const middleware = [

  cookieParser(),
  session({
secret: 'super-secret-key',
key: 'super-secret-cookie',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { maxAge: 1209600000 } // two weeks in miliseconds
  })
]
app.use(middleware);
//var createOrLoginUser = require('./rocketchat');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

if(req.session.rocketchatAuthToken){

    res.send(`
    <html>
        <body>
            <iframe width='100%;' height='100%' src="*redacted*" 
frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>`);

}else{

    res.send(`
        <form method="post" action="/login">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
            <input type="text" placeholder="firstName" 
name="firstname">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email"  name="email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Pass" name="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    `);
}

})
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
// ....CODE TO LOGIN USER

var username    = req.body.username;
var pass        = req.body.password;
var email       = req.body.email;
var name        = req.body.firstname;

// Creating or login user into Rocket chat 
try {

    // Request of login for 3rd party API

    var options = { method: 'GET',
      url: '*redacted*',
      qs: 
       { hashKey: '*redacted*',
         sitename: username,
         password: pass },
      headers: 
       { 'Postman-Token': '*redacted*',
         'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' } };

    const third_party_response = await request(options);
    var result_third_party = JSON.parse(third_party_response);
    console.log(result_third_party);
    console.log(result_third_party.email);

    if(result_third_party.email != ''){

        // Request of login for Rocket Chat

        var options = { method: 'POST',
        url: `${rocketChatServer}/api/v1/login`,
        headers: 
        { 'Postman-Token': '*redacted*',
         'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        form: { username: username, password: pass } };

        const response = await request(options);
        var result = JSON.parse(response);

        req.session.rocketchatAuthToken = result.data.authToken;
        res.redirect('/');








    }else{
        res.send('You are not registered with 3rd party API!');
    }




} catch (ex) { console.log('CATHCh');
    if (ex.statusCode === 401) {

        // User does not exist, creating user
        var options = { method: 'POST',
          url: '*redacted*',
          headers: 
           { 'Postman-Token': '*redacted*',
             'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             'X-User-Id': rocketChatAdminUserId,
             'X-Auth-Token': rocketChatAdminAuthToken },
          form: 
           { name: name ,
             email: email,
             password: pass,
             username: username } };

          const response_register = await request(options);
          var result_register = JSON.parse(response_register);

          if(result_register.success){
            // on success login users 
            var options = { method: 'POST',
            url: `${rocketChatServer}/api/v1/login`,
            headers: 
            { 'Postman-Token': '*redacted*',
             'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            form: { username: username, password: pass } };

            const response = await request(options);
            var result = JSON.parse(response);
            req.session.rocketchatAuthToken = result.data.authToken;
            res.redirect('/');

          }else{
            console.log('Failed to create account');
          }
        // Perfom login
        //return await loginUser(email, password);
    } else {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
})


// This method will be called by Rocket.chat to fetch the login token
app.get('/api/v1/rocket_chat_auth_get', (req, res) => {

if (req.session.rocketchatAuthToken) {
res.send({ loginToken: req.session.rocketchatAuthToken })
return;
} else {
res.status(401).json({ message: 'User not logged in'});
return;
}
})

// This method will be called by Rocket.chat to fetch the login token
// and is used as a fallback
app.get('/api/v1/rocket_chat_iframe', (req, res) => {
const rocketChatServer = '*redacted*';
if (req.session.rocketchatAuthToken) {
return res.send(`<script>
  window.parent.postMessage({
    event: 'login-with-token',
    loginToken: '${ req.session.rocketchatAuthToken }'
  }, '${ rocketChatServer }');
</script>
`)
return;
} else {
return res.redirect('/login');
}
})

app.listen(3030, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3030!');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using the wrong version of node. The `async` keyword requires node 8 or later.

Comment: That's what I thought. I did the command to update to the latest following this documentation: https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs but when I do node -v it still says version 4.2.6

Comment: Fixed by installing NVM, and managing nodeJS through NVM. This answer was correct, it needed the latest version, and by not using NVM it was using some older version of 4.2.6